# Rendering data from api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

```
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("api-url")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.items);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])
if (error) {
  return <div>Error: {error}</div>
} else if (!isLoaded) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else {
  return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          console.log(item)
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

How can I render data from an array of object in typescript?
I am able to see the data when calling console.log(item), console show an array of object with all the data inside it

I've try

```
 <ul>
     {items.map(item => (
       <li key={item.value}>
         {item.label}
       </li>
     ))}
 </ul>
```

The database consist of an array of object - {label: "string", value: "string", boolean: true}
When I try item.label or item.value, I get "Property 'label' does not exist on type 'never'."

Comment: Hi Tuan, could you paste the `console.log(items)` here?

Comment: [{..}{...} .... {...}]
0: {label: "some string", value: "some string", boolean: true}
.
.
9: {label: "some string", value: "some string", boolean: true}

Comment: I solve it, I just need to add useState<any[]>([])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving your "item" the "any" type, to prevent TS from seeing it as "never".

```js
 <ul>
     {items.map((item: Item) => (
       <li key={item.value}>
         {item.label}
       </li>
     ))}
 </ul>
```

Edit: Added the example of a custom Interface, instead of using "any".

```js
interface Item {
  value: string;
  label: string;
  someBOolean: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Workarounds like this means you're just fighting with Typescript, rather than using it the way it is intended. If you know `item` should have `value` and `label` properties, then make an `Item` type, rather than use `any`.

Comment: I've added <any[]> and it work. How do I specify the type for items? The object have label, value, and boolean type.

Comment: Thanks @Oli, that's a fair point. I have updated the answer to have a custom Interface for the Item. For more information about types/interfaces and the difference between them, have a look here: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c

Answer (score 0):

You can define the type of expected values in `useState`, like this:

`const [items, setItems] = useState<Object[]>([]);`

Where `Object` could be the actual interface of your item.